# What is the name of this type of inflorescence?

Tags: botany, reproduction, species-identification

I was having a look at a [rhizophora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhizophora) plant (from the mangrove family), and I got curious about its inflorescence. I can't make out what kind of inflorescence it is.

Here is a photo of the inflorescence.

[image]

Does anyone know which kind of inflorescence it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a woody [compound umbel.](http://www.bcb.uwc.ac.za/ecotree/flowers/inflorescence2.htm) A compound umbel is one with more than one set of [pedicels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedicel_(botany)) between the [peduncle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peduncle_(botany)) and the [flower](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flower). [Hydrangeas also exhibit this type of inflorescence](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/33757/33757-h/images/fig214.jpg), although not necessarily woody.

In the picture below, I've marked all the levels where the pedicels branch.

1. End of peduncle, beginning of primary pedicels
2. Beginning of secondary pedicels
3. Beginning of tertiary pedicels
4. Beginning of quaternary pedicels, which bear flowers

[image]